# create a trigger to Delete from NotSoldTable if found SoldTable

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a Delete Trigger. If the sku is found in sold table need to delete it in not sold table

```
delimiter $$
drop trigger delete_sold_trigger $$
create trigger delete_sold_trigger after insert on soldtable
for each row
begin
IF  soldtable.sku EXIST IN notsoldtable THEN
DELETE from notsoldtable WHERE notsoldtable.sku=soldtable.sku;
END IF;
end$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: *Trying to create a Delete Trigger.* This is AFTER UPDATE trigger - the trigger type is defined by the event which fires it, not by the action performed in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_from_notsoldtable_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON soldtable
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM notsoldtable 
WHERE notsoldtable.sku=NEW.sku;
```